# How to extract the leftover substring from strrchr() or strchr()?

Tags: c, string, string.h, strrchr

Let's say I have the following string which looks like a file path:

```
 char *filepath = "this/is/my/path/to/file.jpg";
```

I can use `strrchr()` to extract `file.jpg` as follows:

```
 char *filename =  strrchr(filepath, '/') + 1;
```

Now I need to extract and store the rest of the string `this/is/my/path/to`. How do I do that in the most effective manner? Please note that I would like to avoid using `strtok()`or `regex` or big iterative loops.

It will be very nice if:

I can apply the same the substring extraction technique to `strchr()` where I have extracted the substring `this` using `strchr(filepath, '/')` and now I need to extract the rest of the substring `is/my/path/to/file.jpg`

Comment: Just copy the first (filename - filepath) characters  to a new location and append a _null character_.  Some additional work needed for the `'/'` seperator, if found.  Yet the post is too unclear for details.  Post what you are tried to do.  Watch out for escape sequences in `"this/is/my/path/to/file.jpg"`.

Comment: @chux:I would like to use `filename` and `filepath` variables to store rest of the substring in  `directory_path` so that if I do a `printf("%s\n", directory_path)`, the output is `this/is/my/path/to`.

Could you please show me how would you code " copy the first (filename - filepath) characters to a new location "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy everything up to the file name, then append a `'\0'` :

```
int   pathLen = filename - filepath;
char *path = (char *) malloc(pathLen + 1);
memcpy(path, filepath, pathLen);
path[pathLen] = '\0';

...

free(path);
```

Comment: To stay on the save side make `pathLen` a `size_t` or even better `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Also in C there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: @alk, The cast is there to get rid of compiler warnings.

Comment: There should not be any warnings **in C**. If there were, something else is wrong.

Comment: @aik, It may depend on your compiler and your chosen warning level.  Either way, what do you perceive as harmful about being explicit ?

Comment: No, any decent C compiler shall not issue a warning, at no level. If it does it's either no C compiler, or it's elder then 30 years, or it's broken.

Comment: Further any cast whose purpose is "to get rid of compiler warnings" is dangerously mismotivated.

Comment: The code as written above is valid C and C++.  Removing the cast makes it invalid C++ and hence the code becomes less portable by removing the cast.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is in writable memory (ie, not a string literal) you can do this

```
char *p =  strrchr(filepath, '/');
*p = '\0';
char *filename = p + 1;
```

this will give you filepath pointing at "this/is/my/path/to" and filename pointing at "file.jpg". Without any copying.

Comment: Not just "in writable memory" but "acceptable to write per your program's contracts of object ownership & mutability".

Comment: As per the OP's code `filepath` points to string literal which's elements may not be changed. So this `*p = '\0';` statement mostly likely will end the program.